# как сделать вывод курса валют одним сообщением?

Tags: python, xml, telegram, telebot

При ответе сообщений курс валют по каждой валюте отправляется отдельным сообщением , как сделать отправку одним сообщением?

```
    for node in elements:
        for child in node.childNodes:
            if child.nodeType == 1:
                if child.tagName == 'Value':
                    if child.firstChild.nodeType == 3:
                        value = float(child.firstChild.data.replace(',', '.'))
                if child.tagName == 'CharCode':
                    if child.firstChild.nodeType == 3:
                        char_code = child.firstChild.data
        if char_code == "USD" or char_code == "EUR" or char_code == "PLN" or char_code == "UAH":
            currency_dict[char_code] = value
    return currency_dict

def print_dict(dict):
    for key in dict.keys():

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{key} = {dict[key]}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def print_dict(dict):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '\n'.join([f'{key} : {value}' for key, value in dict.items()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Так можете попробовать:

```
def print_dict(dict):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(list(dict.values()))
```